# Вывести List<Message> в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, email, pop3

привет.Хочу List  с email вывести в ListBox

```
public void FetchAllMessages()
        {
            using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
            {
                client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
                client.Authenticate(mail, pass);
                messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();
                allMessages = new List<Message>(messageCount);
                for (int i = 0; i > messageCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
                    list.Items.Add(allMessages[i]);
                }

            }
        }
```

Эта функция выполняется при нажатии на кнопку но ListBox не заполняется.Что не так делаю.

Comment: а как привязки сделать

Comment: Но давайте вначале разберемся с проблемой...после изменения знака в цикле: `for (int i = 0; i < messageCount - 1; i++)` все равно данные не отображаются?

Comment: А зачем вам дополнительный лист? listBox1.DataSource = allMessages разве не сработает? Хотя тут уже вопрос типов может встать.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, проблема в том, что вы блокируете UI-поток. Попробуйте чтение отделить от UI-операций.

Кроме того, у вас ошибка в условии цикла: условие `i > messageCount - 1` скорее всего никогда не выполняется.

Затем, что у вас за `Pop3Client`? Стандартного такого класса нет. Если это [OpenPop.NET `Pop3Client`](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.html), у него сообщения нумеруются почему-то [от единицы](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.GetMessage.html).

С учётом этого, получаем такой код:

```
public List<Message> FetchAllMessages()
{
    using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
    {
        client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
        client.Authenticate(mail, pass);
        var messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();
        var messages = new List<Message>(messageCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < messageCount; i++)
            messages.Add(client.GetMessage(i + 1));
        return messages;
    }
}
```

```
allMessages = await Task.Run(() => FetchAllMessages());
messageCount = allMessages.Count;
foreach (var message in allMessages)
    list.Items.Add(message);
```

---

Да, а у `ListBox`'а вам понадобится определить подходящий `ItemTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

xSx сказал, что вопрос типов возможно. И мне так кажется. Вряд ли объект Message  содержит лишь емайл. Скорее всего нужно передавать в лист что-то вроде allMessages[i].fromEmail
Вместо fromEmail там может быть что угодно. Просто поставьте точку после allMessages[i] и посмотрите какие поля объекта предлагаются. Там наверняка что-то с email должно быть.

Это если вы со знаком все-таки очепятались)